# I want to Switch UIView by Clicking UISegmented Control but my Code is not working

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

i want to Switch UIView by clicking Segmented Control but this Code is not working.

```
@IBOutlet weak var flightTypeSegCont: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func flightType(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        if(flightTypeSegCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {
            self.direcrCard.isHidden = false
            self.ViaCardView.isHidden = true
        }
        else
        {
            self.direcrCard.isHidden = true
            self.ViaCardView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: Please Check Edited Question

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan Debug view hierarchy

Comment: still not working

Comment: One other point - hiding views is additive - you should only hide a view if it is not already hidden, and only unhide a view if it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you check if the function is getting called in XCode debugger? If not, connect IBAction from storyboard / xib to your function - valuechanged callout of `UISegmentedControl`.
2. If it is being called but views are not hidden as you want, check if they are having parent/child relationship. To check this in more details, go to `XCode->View Debugging->Capture View hierarchy` option to see the runtime UIView layout.

Comment: what's not working..you must answer the steps shown. Without details, no one can help you.

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan Check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html